# Is there a better way?: iterating over an array in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm working on a mini project for a summer class. I'd like some feedback on the code I have written, especially part 3.

Here's the question:

1. Create an array called numbers containing the integers 1 - 10 and assign it to a variable.
2. Create an empty array called even_numbers.
3. Create a method that iterates over the array. Place all even numbers in the array even_numbers.
4. Print the array even_numbers.

Here's my code, so far:

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

print numbers[3]

even_numbers.empty?
def even_numbers
    numbers.sort!
```

end

Comment: Your code doesn't parse; Ruby needs `end` to terminate blocks like function definitions. Look into using Array#select though.

Comment: Please read "[ask]". Make sure your sample code meets the requirements and it does what you want, is syntactically correct, then look at [codereview.se] and see if that'd be a better fit for your question. As is, it doesn't meet the requirements, nor is it syntactically correct and it won't do what you want.

Comment: Thank you @theTinMan. I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing explicit iteration, the best way is likely `Array#select` thus:

```
even_numbers = numbers.select { |n| n.even? }
```

which will run the block given on each element in the array `numbers` and produce an array containing all elements for which the block returned true.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

or an alternative solution following the convention of your problem:

```
def get_even_numbers(array)
        even_num = []
        array.each do |n|
            even_num << n if n.even?    
        end   
    even_num
end
```

and of course going for the select method is always preferred.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I see where my code needs improvement.